# Uniform distribution probability

Tags: probability, statistics

A 5km road running north and south, the location of a crime is a uniform random variable. The city is trying to place the police station at the best location

(a) If the police headquarters were located at km n = 3, find the cdf and pdf of the distance to a crime.

(b) Now suppose the police headquarters is located at km n for some n from 0 to 5. Find the cdf and pdf of the distance to a crime.

Hint: Note that, if n is in [0, 2.5] (i.e., the police headquarters is located closer to the north end of the road), then the largest distance that would need to be travelled to a crime is (5 - n)
and it is n if n is in [2.5, 5]. That is, the possible values of the random variable for the distance to a crime are in the interval [0; max{5-n,n}].

(c) Using the PDF found in part (b), compute the expected value of the distance to a crime.

(d) Where would you recommend the city to locate a new police headquarters and why?

This is my work so far.
X~uniform (0,5)
Y = crime given distance = |x-3|

$F_{Y} $ = P(Y $\leq$ y)
         = P(|x-3| $\leq$ y)
         = P((3-y)$\leq$ x $\leq$ (y+3))
and i end up with

$F_x$(y+3) - $F_x$(3-y)

I"m not sure how to continue with this question.

Comment: To avoid confussion always remember that symbols for random variables, and values, are case sensitive.  $X$ is your random variable, $x$ is something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is correct so far.   $F_Y(y) = F_X(3+y)-F_X(3-y)$ . (Note: capitalisation.)

Now consider that $F_X(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & :& x\leqslant 0\\ x/5 &:& 0< x < 5\\ 1 &:& x\geqslant 5\end{cases}$

So, therefore $F_Y(y) = \begin{cases} 0 &:& y\leqslant 0 \\ \bbox[border:1pt pink solid]{\phantom{2y/5\qquad}} &:& 0< y < 2 \\ \bbox[border:1pt pink solid]{\phantom{(y+2)/5}} &:& 2\leqslant y < 3 \\ 1 &:& 3\leq y \end{cases}$

Another way to view it is that you have folded a bit of the original distribution onto itself, so the density in this merged interval will be twice that of the original.   Thus the probability density function is:

$$f_Y(y) ~{=\begin{cases} f_X(3+y)+f_X(3-y) & :& 0<y < 2 \\ f_X(3-y) &:& 2\leqslant y< 3\\ 0 & :& \text{elsewhere} \end{cases} \\= \begin{cases} 2/5 &:& 0< y < 2 \\ 1/5 &:& 2\leqslant y < 3 \\ 0 &:& \text{otherwise} \end{cases}}$$

From which you can find the CDF.

Comment: in the cdf and pdf are there always three cases and two cases respectively? Would there be a scenario where there are more cases?

Comment: Yes, there may be more cases.  As in this senario.

Comment: for part b i separated it into range from 0 to 2.5 and 2.5 to 5, however when i did the calculations i got 2y/5 for both of them and doesn't seem correct to me.

Comment: That is the correct value of the CDF in the fold, its the size of the folded and the unfolded intervals that distinguish the CDF for different values of $n$.

Comment: So the cdf would look something like 2y/5 when y is [0,2.5] and 2y/5 when (2.5,5] ?

Comment: Hint: relate the CDF to the value of $n$, the placement of the police station.

Comment: I don't quite understand the hint. if n is exactly 2.5 then which n would i choose since the question states that if n is in [0,2.5] then y= 5-n and if n is in [2.5,5] then distance to crime is n.

Comment: The hint *is* that the support for $Y$ is $[0;5-n]$ *when* $0\leq n\leq 2.5$, and the support is $[0;n]$ *when* $2.5< n\leq 5$.  When $n=2.5$ then the support for $Y$ is $[0;2.5]$.  $n$ itself is a parameter taking on values in $[0;5]$

Comment: Your task is to express $F_Y(y; n)$, the CDF for $Y$, the distance to the crime, when the police station is at position $n$.  Generalising from part (a) where you expressed $F_Y(y; 3)$.

Comment: does this mean that there should be two cdfs? because i have no idea how to generate the cdf for this problem.

Comment: No it means you will have a piecewise function in terms of $n$ as well as $y$.